# How many words exist that have exactly $5$ distinct consonants and $2$ identical vowels?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

I'm new to combinatorics, Although I understood most of the concepts this one baffles me.

> How many words exist that have exactly $5$ distinct consonants and $2$ identical vowels?

The Answer is $$\binom{21}{5} \binom{5}{1} \frac{7!}{2!}$$

My doubt is:
   Why do we write $\binom{5}{1}$ when we have to select 2 vowels?(Answers with examples appreciated).

Comment: Because you are **choosing** only one vowel. [ The permutations take care of the fact that there are $7$ letters of which two are identical]

Answer (score 1):

Since we have 2 **identical** vowels, we should to choose only one "kind" of vowels to put it in two places.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting 1 vowel (since your problem requires 2 *identical* ones) and then choosing where to place consonants and vowels in $7!/2!$ ways

Comment: So If the question requires 5 distinctive consonants and 3 identical vowels the answer would be 21C5 * 5C1 * 8!/3!